# How to process sensor time series data in batch (e.g. every 1 minute) to time series database (e.g. CrateDB) via FIWARE ORION CONTEXT BROKER?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, cratedb

I want to process sensor data into a time series database via **FIWARE ORION CONTEXT BROKER**. However, instead of writing each data individually, I want to write it **collectively** as a 1-minute time series. Is something like this possible?

Could you help me? What path should I follow?

Comment: What did you looked for/tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this problem into separate parts. Firstly define the payload of your batch operation. If the device can collect a series of readings and then deliver them **as NGSI** you can use the `/v2/op/update/` for **NGSI-v2** or `/ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert` for **NGSI-LD**

For **NGSI-v2** it would be something like

```sh
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/v2/op/update/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "actionType":"append",
  "entities":[
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:002",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 21,
            "metadata":{
                "unitCode": "CEL",
                "TimeInstant": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "XXXX-XXX-XXXXX"
                 }
           }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:003",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 27,
            "metadata":{
                "unitCode": "CEL",
                "TimeInstant": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "XXXX-XXX-XXXXX"
                 }
           }
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

For **NGSI-LD** it would be something like this:

```sh
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Link: <http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
--data-raw '[
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:002",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 21,
            "unitCode": "CEL",
            "observedAt": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:003",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 27,
            "unitCode": "CEL",
            "observedAt": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX"
      }
    }
]'
```

The important thing here is to include the `observedAt` or `TimeInstant` in the payload so that it can be passed when creating a subscription into QuantumLeap (amend the `fiware-service` to the correct Tenant:

```sh
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "description": "Notify QuantumLeap of temperature changes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "TemperatureSensor.*"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "count"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ],
    "metadata": ["dateCreated", "TimeInstant"]
  },
  "throttling": 1
}'
```

Now it could be the case that you have a device writing to a file and periodically uploading a batch of readings. In this case you can create a Custom IoT Agent which deciphers the payload and transforms each reading into a batch upsert request - an example can be found in this [FIWARE Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuEwI8wJKFU&t=1607s) on YouTube.

The steps are always the same:

1. Ingest the payload holding the readings (in format X)
2. Transform format X to an in-memory representation.
3. Tweak the representation into the `entities` part of an NGSI request
4. Send the upsert to the context broker.

The subscription to [QuantumLeap](https://quantumleap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will persist the data to a database where you can make time-series queries. The [FIWARE Tutorial](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/time-series-data.html) will cover the steps.

Now if you are using NGSI-LD you can still use QuantumLeap, but you could also look at using the Temporal interface directly. More details in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcfJOx7g7jI&t=2500s)

Comment: If I want to batch write the data obtained in 5 seconds, is it enough to set the "throttling" parameter to 5 in the Orion-QuantumLeap subscription? @JasonFox

Comment: No, that  will merely select samples from the data at a rate of not more than every 5 seconds. The batch write is a CRUD write **into** the context broker, whereas `throttling` is a subscription parameter on change of context coming *out* of the context broker.